# How to create a form text field with required attribute in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Like

```
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

How I'll create a form text field with `required` attribute in Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
{{ Form::text('usrname', Input::old('usrname', 'default value'), array('required')) }}
```

The array passed in as the third parameter handles all attributes of the `HTML` tag you are creating within the Form::text.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, [extra attributes can be passed as an array](http://laravel.com/docs/html#text) in the `text` method:

```
{{ Form::text('usrname', 'Default Value', array('required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your username here')) }}
```